# How does the Stackoverflow footer animation work?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, animation

How does the Stackoverflow footer animation work?

Particularly clicking on one element (e.g. Technology), to expand into more.

Comment: There are many libraries for tabs and accordions that perform animation when opening them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main "trick" is to have all elements present, but not all shown. The currently shown lists are given the `_visible` class:

```
max-width: 200px;
opacity: 1;
```

And those lists not shown are by default:

```
max-width: 0
opacity: 0
```

When the class is added or removed, the transition property `all ease-in-out .15s` nicely animates each element.

A jQuery approach would be using `$('selector').toggleClass('_visible');`.  This site is probably not using jQuery to toggle the classes, but it achieves the same result.

```js
$('#tech, button').on('click', function() {
  $('nav, button').toggleClass('_visible');
})
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

div>* {
  -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
  flex: 1 auto;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  transition: all ease-in-out .15s;
}

nav,
button {
  max-width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

nav>ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

._visible {
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button><svg role="icon" class="svg-icon iconArrowLeftAlt" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="M10.58 16L12 14.59 6.4 9 12 3.41 10.57 2l-7 7z"></path></svg></button>
<div>
  <nav class="_visible">
    <ul>
      <li id=tech>Technology</li>
      <li>Life / Arts</li>
      <li>Culture / Recreation</li>
      <li>Science</li>
      <li>Other</li>
      <li>Mobile</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Stack Overflow</li>
      <li>Server Fault</li>
      <li>Super User</li>
      <li>Web Applications</li>
      <li>Ask Ubuntu</li>
      <li>Webmasters</li>
      <li>Game Development</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>TeX - LaTeX</li>
      <li>Software Engineering</li>
      <li>Unix &amp; Linux</li>
      <li>Ask Different (Apple)</li>
      <li>WordPress Development</li>
      <li>Geographic Information Systems</li>
      <li>Electrical Engineering</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Android Enthusiasts</li>
      <li>Information Security</li>
      <li>Database Administrators</li>
      <li>Drupal Answers</li>
      <li>SharePoint</li>
      <li>User Experience</li>
      <li>Mathematica</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Salesforce</li>
      <li>ExpressionEngine® Answers</li>
      <li>Blender</li>
      <li>Network Engineering</li>
      <li>Cryptography</li>
      <li>Code Review</li>
      <li>Magento</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Software Recommendations</li>
      <li>Signal Processing</li>
      <li>Emacs</li>
      <li>Raspberry Pi</li>
      <li>Programming Puzzles &amp; Code Golf</li>
      <li>Ethereum</li>
      <li>Data Science</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav class="_visible">
    <ul>
      <li>Blog</li>
      <li>Facebook</li>
      <li>Twitter</li>
      <li>LinkedIn</li>
      <li>site design / logo © 2017 Stack Exchange Inc</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```